# Standard cyclic representation of $sl(2, F)$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $x, y, h,$ be the standard basis of the Lie algebra $sl(2, F)$, and $R=\{\pm\alpha\},$ the associated root system. I wanted to compute the weight space decomposition of $Z(\alpha),$ the standard cyclic module of highest weight $\alpha.$

I know that $Z(\alpha)$ has basis $y^nv^+$, and $y^nv^+\in V_ {(1-n)\alpha} \ $, since we have $\ hy^nv^+ = -2y^nv^+ +yhy^{n-1}v^+ $, and the rest follows by induction. Thus:

$$Z(\alpha)=\bigoplus_{n=-1}^\infty V_{-n\alpha}$$

I now wanted to compute the unique irreducible quotient of $Z(\alpha)$, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you compute that $y^3v^+$ is a highest weight vector ? And $\bigoplus_{n=2}^\infty V_{-n\alpha}$ is the unique maximal submodule of $Z(\alpha)$.

Comment: @DavidHill $xy^nv^+=n(3-n)y^{n-1}v^+$, hence $y^3v^+$ is a maximal vector, thanks!